# Is there any way to prove it directly?

Tags: general-topology, logic

I'm trying to prove the following result:

> In a first countable $T_1$ space $X$ for $E\subset X,~x\in X$ is an adherent point of $E\iff~\exists~(x_n)_n\in E$ such that $x_n\to x.$

When I'm considering the $E=\emptyset,$ I can't prove it directly without using $$\{\text{if}~~p\iff q~~\text{then}~~-p\iff -q\}$$

Is there any way to prove it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the implication $\bigl(\exists x_n \in E\bigr)(x_n \to x) \Rightarrow x \in \overline{E}$ without any assumptions on the space, by the definition of convergence and closure.

Conversely, let $x \in \overline{E}$, and $U_1 \supset U_2 \supset \ldots U_k \supset U_{k+1} \ldots$ a countable neighbourhood basis of $x$. Then choose $x_n \in U_n \cap E$ to get a sequence $(x_n)$ in $E$ converging to $x$.